# ScrollView Image -Page Control iOS

Tags: ios, scroll

In the following implementation, images has been got from database, Once I put a debug point and see how many images that webservice returns, it shows five. However, on my scrollview, only three images appears.

```
-(void) setSizeSliding
{
    for (int i = 0; i < colors.count; i++) {
        CGRect frame;
        frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * i;
        frame.origin.y = 0;
        frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;

        NSString*slidingImage = [[colors objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"picture"];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:slidingImage];
        NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
        UIImage *tmpImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];

        UIImageView *slidingImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:frame];
        slidingImageView.image = tmpImage;
        [self.scrollView addSubview:slidingImageView];
    }

    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width * colors.count, self.scrollView.frame.size.height);


}
```

**Update:**

if I change the page control pages property, then I could able to scroll up to all five images. However, how could I avoid to put a const value?

[image]

Comment: have you check you got `tmpImage` for all?

Comment: It loops 5 times.I got images to display on scrollview but only 3 of them are displaying.

Comment: yes you'll get `colors.count = 5` but check in for loop that you got all images as per count?

Comment: have you checked the scrollview contentsize correctly ? as I think there is problem with your content size

Comment: @casillas you can change page size using code. `yourPagecontrol.numberOfPages = 10;` and also set currentpage using `pagec.currentPage = 5;`

Comment: but it should not be hard coded

Comment: @casillas if you don't assign some value to pageControl how it knows that how many pages to show. so you must have to assign some value. like in tableview without giving numberofrows table doesnt know how many rows to display. same way for page contorl you have to assign some value at any time.

Comment: I have found the solution and posted below. Thanks a lot Chinttu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution, once I have added `self.pageControl.numberOfPages` into my code, it works.

```
 -(void) setSizeSliding
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < colors.count; i++) {
            CGRect frame;
            frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * i;
            frame.origin.y = 0;
            frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;

            NSString*slidingImage = [[colors objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"picture"];
            NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:slidingImage];
            NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
            UIImage *tmpImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];

            UIImageView *slidingImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:frame];
            slidingImageView.image = tmpImage;
            [self.scrollView addSubview:slidingImageView];
        }

        self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width * colors.count, self.scrollView.frame.size.height);
   //solution    
   // the following code needs to be added to handle number of pages
    self.pageControl.numberOfPages = colors.count;


    }
```